# how to set selected option of <select> in php

Tags: php, html

I need to save my info and after submit button I need to output all info also I need selected option to stay selected after submit button on my form. 
My code output the info but the output contain the number for state and I need the state to be output as string

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$state = $_POST['state'];
$file = $name.".txt";
$txt = $name.",".$state.",";
$wrt = file_put_contents($file, $txt, FILE_APPEND);
$get_file = file_get_contents($file);

$info = array($get_file);
foreach($info as $k => $v)
echo $p;
$x = explode(",",$v);

?>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <input name="name" value="<?php echo $x['0'];?>"/>
        <select name="state">
            <option value="0"> Stat</option>
            <?php
            $province = array("AA", "AE" ,'AK" , "AL" , "AP" , "AR" ,    "AS" , "AZ" , "CA" , "CO" , "CT" , "DC" , "DE" , "FL" , "FM" , "GA" , "GU" , "HI" , "IA" , "ID" , "IL" , "IN" , "KS" , "KY" , "LA" , "MA" , "MD" , "ME" , "MH" , "MI" , "MN" , "MP" , "MO" , "MS" , "MT" , "NC" , "ND" , "NE" , "NH" , "NJ" , "NM" , "NV" , "NY" , "OH" , "OK" , "OR" , "PA" , "PR" , "PW" , "RI" , "SC" , "SD" , "TN" , "TX" , "UT" , "VA" , "VI" , "VT" , "WA" , "WI" , "WV" , "WY');
            foreach($province as $k => $v)
            echo "<option value='".($k+1)."'>$v</option>";
            ?> 
        <input type ="submit" name="submit" value="trimite"/>
        </select>
    </form>
```

Comment: <option value="" selected> is missing in your code .

Comment: also instead of using `$k+1` you could set the array like so `$province = array(1 => "AA", "AE" ,'AK", ...);`, just a little tip.

Answer (score 2):

Please check the below code:-

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)){
   $name = $_POST['name'];
   $state = $_POST['state'];
   // I don't know what you are doing here through this code
   /* $file = $name.".txt";
   $txt = $name.",".$state.",";
   $wrt = file_put_contents($file, $txt, FILE_APPEND);
   $get_file = file_get_contents($file);

   $info = array($get_file);
   foreach($info as $k => $v)
    echo $p;
    $x = explode(",",$v); */
}
?>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <input name="name" value="<?php if (isset($name)){echo $name;}?>"/>
        <select name="state">
            <option value="0"> Stat</option>
            <?php
            $province = array("AA", "AE" ,'AK" , "AL" , "AP" , "AR" ,    "AS" , "AZ" , "CA" , "CO" , "CT" , "DC" , "DE" , "FL" , "FM" , "GA" , "GU" , "HI" , "IA" , "ID" , "IL" , "IN" , "KS" , "KY" , "LA" , "MA" , "MD" , "ME" , "MH" , "MI" , "MN" , "MP" , "MO" , "MS" , "MT" , "NC" , "ND" , "NE" , "NH" , "NJ" , "NM" , "NV" , "NY" , "OH" , "OK" , "OR" , "PA" , "PR" , "PW" , "RI" , "SC" , "SD" , "TN" , "TX" , "UT" , "VA" , "VI" , "VT" , "WA" , "WI" , "WV" , "WY');
            foreach($province as $k=> $v){
                if(isset($state) && $state == $k){
                    echo "<option value='".$k."' selected = 'selected'>$v</option>";
                }else{
                    echo "<option value='".$k."'>$v</option>";
                }
            }
            ?> 

        </select>
        <input type ="submit" name="submit" value="trimite" style = "margin-top:30px;"/>
    </form>
```

Comment: good one the code work perfectly in my html thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Something like this is the way I ususally do it:

```
foreach($province as $k => $v) {
    $sel = ($state == $k) ? " selected='selected'" : "";
    echo "<option value='".($k+1)."' {$sel}>{$v}</option>";
}
```